# Can I display an extended ASCII manual page from the shell?

Tags: shell, unix

The same way I can display the 7-bit ASCII table from the shell by invoking `man ascii`, is there a way to get the 8-bit extended ASCII table from the shell? (I am using the BSD Unix edition.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII: "There are many extended ASCII encodings (more than 220 DOS and Windows codepages)."  Which one would you want?

Comment: There is no *one* 8-bit extended ASCII character set; rather, there are many with different ones, depending on which language the character set is intended to support.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no man page for any of them in any of the standard distributions.

Comment: This may have made my day — or so-so: I am retrieving data from an old Macintosh (OS 9) in French.

Comment: @Nate Elredge. Not sure… Please see my reply/comment to chepner hereunder.

Comment: Online: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/iso_8859-1.7.html (Or you can pick up the individual man page sources from https://github.com/mkerrisk/man-pages/tree/master/man7)

Answer (score 0):

Use man ascii to view the ascii codes. In the last view lines the page lists a few other codes. Pick the one you want. Quit man, then open it again with the code you want. For example man iso_8859-4

Comment: Sorry: in the implementation of Unix that is on my computer (BSD, Darwin, version 7 of AT&T),  the last lines, right under "the decimal set" read: "Files" and "History". Please check and confirm your post.

Comment: In the  Linux man pages the other pages are listed as See Also. You can also try man charsets

Comment: Sorry, Paul, BSD UNIX, not Linux, as specified in my original post: no "man charsets" available, either. Do not mix up Unix (along with its multiple variants and dialects)  with Linux.